# What are the right adjectives to refer to changes in gravity?

Tags: phrases, word-usage

How should one refer to the changes in gravity?
Should one say: *"gravity became higher/lower"* or *"gravity became lighter/heavier?"*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Gravity is a force, and forces are *strong* or *weak* (and hence ***stronger*** and ***weaker***).

While one might hesitate to quote Wikipedia as justification, its crowdsourcing can be valuable.

> Parameters affecting the apparent or actual strength of Earth's gravity include latitude, altitude, and the local topography and geology.
>
> Red shows the areas where gravity is stronger than the smooth, standard value, and blue reveals areas where gravity is weaker.
>
> ...an object at the Equator experiences a weaker gravitational pull than an object at the poles.
>
> [Gravity of Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth)

Answer (score 4):

This is clearly not an everyday occurrence, unless you refer to the acceleration which takes place as a body falls further. I assume you refer to what happens when you go into space. My inclination would be to use 'increased' and 'diminished'.